# What does Google use 173.194.90.xxx IP's for? Why is it not a googlebot.com pointer?

Tags: googlebot, feeds

I've been noticing this new Google range hitting our feeds over the last couple weeks. It's bordering on abusing our resources with multiple hits in short timeframe. The `173.194.90.xxx` IP's fall under the Google ASN but it still seems phishy. Reverse DNS doesn't resolve (NXDOMAIN), and the user agent is simply [Googlebot]. A friend suggested it was a pub DNS exit IP, but I can't tell.

Has anyone else got hits from this range? Is this a legit Googlebot? Since it hits feeds/maps, perhaps it has something to do with feed quality checking?

EDIT: in addition to the above mentioned range, there is also `74.125.72.xxx` range acting the same way on feeds.

Comment: This question is off-topic [because it is not about a site you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards This question is about a site I control... "hitting our feeds" means we own the feeds... The question is about DNS routing and whether or not we should allow this IP to hit the feeds in a rather abusive manner. I have edited the question to make that more clear.

Comment: OK, sorry then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is within the Googlebot ranges. Here is my list based upon past accesses. Please forgive the crude wildcards.

```
64.233.160.*
64.233.161.*
64.233.162.*
64.233.163.*
64.233.164.*
64.233.165.*
64.233.166.*
64.233.167.*
64.233.168.*
64.233.169.*
64.233.170.*
64.233.171.*
64.233.172.*
64.233.173.*
64.233.174.*
64.233.175.*
64.233.176.*
64.233.177.*
64.233.178.*
64.233.179.*
64.233.180.*
64.233.181.*
64.233.182.*
64.233.183.*
64.233.184.*
64.233.185.*
64.233.186.*
64.233.187.*
64.233.188.*
64.233.189.*
64.233.190.*
64.233.191.*
66.249.64.*
66.249.65.*
66.249.66.*
66.249.67.*
66.249.68.*
66.249.69.*
66.249.70.*
66.249.71.*
66.249.72.*
66.249.73.*
66.249.74.*
66.249.75.*
66.249.76.*
66.249.77.*
66.249.78.*
66.249.79.*
66.249.80.*
66.249.82.*
66.249.83.*
66.249.84.*
66.249.85.*
66.249.86.*
66.249.87.*
66.249.88.*
66.249.89.*
66.249.90.*
66.249.91.*
66.249.92.*
66.249.93.*
66.249.94.*
66.249.95.*
74.125.*
173.194.*
```

The following ranges have been used for other Google search related bots which still may be the case. However, it is also part of the Google e-mail services they provide to web sites and used for web hosting.

```
209.85.128.*
209.85.129.*
209.85.130.*
209.85.131.*
209.85.132.*
209.85.133.*
209.85.134.*
209.85.135.*
209.85.136.*
209.85.137.*
209.85.138.*
209.85.139.*
209.85.140.*
209.85.141.*
209.85.142.*
209.85.143.*
209.85.144.*
209.85.145.*
209.85.146.*
209.85.147.*
209.85.148.*
209.85.149.*
209.85.150.*
209.85.151.*
209.85.152.*
209.85.153.*
209.85.154.*
209.85.155.*
209.85.156.*
209.85.157.*
209.85.158.*
209.85.159.*
209.85.160.*
209.85.161.*
209.85.162.*
209.85.163.*
209.85.164.*
209.85.165.*
209.85.166.*
209.85.167.*
209.85.168.*
209.85.169.*
209.85.170.*
209.85.171.*
209.85.172.*
209.85.173.*
209.85.174.*
209.85.175.*
209.85.176.*
209.85.177.*
209.85.178.*
209.85.179.*
209.85.180.*
209.85.181.*
209.85.182.*
209.85.183.*
209.85.184.*
209.85.185.*
209.85.186.*
209.85.187.*
209.85.188.*
209.85.189.*
209.85.190.*
209.85.191.*
209.85.192.*
209.85.193.*
209.85.194.*
209.85.195.*
209.85.196.*
209.85.197.*
209.85.198.*
209.85.199.*
209.85.200.*
209.85.201.*
209.85.202.*
209.85.203.*
209.85.204.*
209.85.205.*
209.85.206.*
209.85.207.*
209.85.208.*
209.85.209.*
209.85.210.*
209.85.211.*
209.85.212.*
209.85.213.*
209.85.214.*
209.85.215.*
209.85.216.*
209.85.217.*
209.85.218.*
209.85.219.*
209.85.220.*
209.85.221.*
209.85.222.*
209.85.223.*
209.85.224.*
209.85.225.*
209.85.226.*
209.85.227.*
209.85.228.*
209.85.229.*
209.85.230.*
209.85.231.*
209.85.232.*
209.85.233.*
209.85.234.*
209.85.235.*
209.85.236.*
209.85.237.*
209.85.238.*
209.85.239.*
209.85.240.*
209.85.241.*
209.85.242.*
209.85.243.*
209.85.244.*
209.85.245.*
209.85.246.*
209.85.247.*
209.85.248.*
209.85.249.*
209.85.250.*
209.85.251.*
209.85.252.*
209.85.253.*
209.85.254.*
209.85.255.*
```

The following ranges have also been used for Google search bot activity in the past but not likely recently. However, this range does appear to be for web hosting.

```
216.239.32.*
216.239.33.*
216.239.34.*
216.239.35.*
216.239.36.*
216.239.37.*
216.239.38.*
216.239.39.*
216.239.40.*
216.239.41.*
216.239.42.*
216.239.43.*
216.239.44.*
216.239.45.*
216.239.46.*
216.239.47.*
216.239.48.*
216.239.49.*
216.239.50.*
216.239.51.*
216.239.52.*
216.239.53.*
216.239.54.*
216.239.55.*
216.239.56.*
216.239.57.*
216.239.58.*
216.239.59.*
216.239.60.*
216.239.61.*
216.239.62.*
216.239.63.*
```

It is unfortunate that Google has decided to be so dynamic with their IP addresses. They are confusing the security world. Their solution is to reverse the IP address to a domain name to ensure that any bot is from Google. But most web servers do not have that option available natively. As well, not all of the Google IP addresses reverse to a domain name. I do have to trim my list. It is hand generated from my database. I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow that 216 range is vintage :) Microsoft is becoming the same way, too obscure. They have some new ranges that are almost the same as some heavy spammers. Example 104.45.228.136

Comment: My database reaches back 6-7 years... Thanks for the Mickeysquish (also vintage) IP range. I have a wild carded list for them as well if you need it. Again, hand edited.